# Formation of words like "essive" or "adessive"

Tags: adjective, new-latin, derivation

In modern linguistic terminology there are grammatical cases named *essive* and *adessive*. However, from a Latinate point of view those formations look abnormal: Usually, the ending *-ivus* is attached to the supine stem (past participle) that is missing for the Latin verb *esse*.

I tried [this query to Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=essiv&lang=la) and found some matches for words ending in *-essivus*, but none of them is derived from *esse*. Thus, the formation of *essive* is post-classical.

When were the terms like *essive* created and how are they motivated?

Comment: The OED dates it in English from 1890, but derives it from Finnish _essiivi_, formed from the Latin; but I don't know when it was created in Finnish. As for the motivation, that seems pretty obvious: once Latinate grammarians were let loose on Finnish, they had to make up Latinate names for all the "cases", and most of them ended in _-ive_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Esse* is a wonderfully common and useful verb, but also a somewhat defective one: it's missing various forms that other verbs have. Some of these missing forms were stolen from unrelated verbs, like the whole perfect system, taken from an older verb "to become". Others remained as gaps all through the Classical period.

For example, *esse* has no present participle ("being"). This became a problem when translating philosophical works from Greek: the common philosophical term *οὐσία* "essence" was built off the Greek present participle, but Latin didn't have an equivalent form to use. So Classical translators compensated by replacing the missing form with *ess-* and continuing from there: **ess-ent-* > *essentia*.

When post-classical grammarians and linguists needed to make new case names, they ran into an equivalent problem. Names of cases are generally built off the supine stem, but all the best verbs for "to be present" are compounds of *esse*, which has no supine. So they used the same solution: replacing the missing participle stem with *ess-*, and going from there: **ad-ess-iv-* > "adessive".

Comment: This is reminiscent of the way *esse* is got reanalyzed in some Romance languages. Consider the Italian *essere*.

Comment: It’s a great answer but I am worried that you may be chasing the wrong fox when you talk about present participles. Surely the “present participle” direction is a description of the word *ens*?

Comment: @MartinKochanski As I understand it, *esse* actually had three present participles over the years! *Sōns* ~ *sēns* drifted semantically until its original meaning was lost (but see _absēns_ etc); *_essens_ was created by Classical authors as an intermediate stage in translating Greek _ousía_ (from the Greek present participle of the copula), and _ēns_ was created in Mediaeval Latin by analogy with Greek (because the AGrk participle of the copula looks like a bare ending with no stem). I don't think any two of these ever coexisted.

Comment: @MartinKochanski …though now that I think of it that might be a good question in its own right; feel free to ask, if you don't, I'll do it later