# Present participles of the verb esse

Tags: vocabulary, participle, irregular-words, esse, loanwords

Inspired by the answers to [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/formation-of-words-like-essive-or-adessive), I want to ask about the different present participles of *esse* over time and their fate. I am aware that *esse* is a defective verb that classically does not have a present participle. But there are frozen forms like *absens* suggesting an old form **sens* for a present participle, and there is *ens* calqued from Greek. The word *essentia* "essence", another calque from Greek, also suggests a form like **essens*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Good question!

In the beginning, way back in the far-flung times of Proto-Indo-European, the word for "it is" was something like **h₁ésti*, and it had a fairly regular present participle, **h₁sónts*. In Latin, these forms evolved into *est* and *sōns*, respectively (vowels get lengthened before *-ns*). The latter is where we get forms like *absēns* > "absent" and *praesēns* > "present", with vowel reduction in non-initial syllables. (This reduction evidently happened before the lengthening.)

But over time, the meaning of this word started to drift. In legal language, "the one who is" started to mean "the real one", then "the actual perpetrator", then "the guilty one", and eventually *sōns* became synonymous with *reus*. So it didn't really work as a participle any more.

People then made do without a present participle for quite a while, until they had to translate philosophical texts from Greek. The philosophical term *οὐσία* "essence" was formed from the Greek present participle plus the noun-forming *-ία*. And while the latter had a nice equivalent in Latin (*-ia*), the former didn't. So some translators took the infinitive *esse*, built a fake participle off that (**essens*), and attached *-ia* onto the end of that, giving *essentia*. *Essentia* caught on (hence English "essence" and all its cognates), but **essens* didn't.

Eventually, in Mediaeval Latin, people started to question the lack of a present participle (since Greek and Romance had one). The Ancient Greek one in particular was *ὤν* (also from **h₁sónts*; initial `/s/` tended to vanish in Greek), which coincidentally looked just like the standard participle *ending* (as in *λύ-ων* "releasing"). So by analogy, they took the ending off the Latin present participle, and started using it as a word of its own: *curr-ēns, curr-entis* > *ēns, entis*. While it's not Classical, this is probably the most popular participle you'll find, and will be the most easily understood nowadays.

Comment: This _ēns/entis_ is where e.g. SP _ente_ and EN _entity_ come from, right?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I believe so, yes!

Answer (score 6):

In medieval Latin there were  neologisms such as [ens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ens#Etymology_3). The link also says that the original form was [sons](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sons#Latin) with the classical meaning "guilty".